# What's a good way to unit test dc.js rendered charts when used in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, dc.js

What's a good way to test dc.js rendered charts when used in react. We use enzymes currently for react testing. Enzymes being a react test library cannot find the html rendered by dc.js.

Comment: I don't know react or enzymes, but we use Jasmine for testing dc.js and it works pretty well. Testing SVG output is always a bit opaque, though.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for the response.